# C# value is always 0 console application

Tags: c#, console-application, calculator

I have no idea why my BMI value is always = to 0. I am programming noob what am i missing? other than that is my if statement alright? what am i missing?

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        double WeightKg = 0.0, HeightCm = 0.0, Weightlbs = 0.0, WeightOz = 0.0, BMI = 0.0, Feet = 0.0, Inches = 0.0;
        int BMIOption;
        string AnotherConversion;

        string BMIMenu = ("Which Measurement You Want to use to enter the weight and height?"
                        + "\n1)Enter 1 for Metric"
                        + "\n2)Enter 2 for British Imperial:");
        Console.Write(BMIMenu);
        BMIOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (BMIOption == 1) {
            Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Weight in Kilogram (kg):");
            WeightKg = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Height in in centimetres (cm):");
            HeightCm = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            BMI = WeightKg / (HeightCm * HeightCm);

            if (BMI >= 35) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:C},Severe Obesity", BMI);
            } else if (BMI >= 30) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:C},Obese", BMI);
            } else if (BMI >= 25) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:C},OverWeight", BMI);
            } else if (BMI >= 18.5) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:C},Healthy BodyWeight", BMI);
            } else if (BMI <= 18.5) {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:C},UnderWeight", BMI);
            }//End if

            Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What are the values of `WeightKg` and `HeightCm` ?

Comment: Hi noob. Right NOW is the time to learn how to use the debugger, before you write another line of code:)

Comment: Why are you using int.Parse when you values are obviously floating-point doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMI is calculated with meters, not centimeters. So you need to convert the `HeightCm` to `HeightM`. If you don't do this, you get really small number, that is then printed as 0.

```
double HeightM = HeightCm / 100.0;
BMI = WeightKg / (HeightM * HeightM);
```

Also, when parsing, use `double.Parse` instead of `int.Parse`. The way it is right now, you will only parse the number without the decimal part.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
BMI = WeightKg / (HeightCm * HeightCm);
```

The result ends up being very small (less than 1). Take an example where `WeightKg` is 55 and `HeightCm` is 165. The result is around 0.002.

When you display it as `{0:C}`, it's being displayed as zero. Use `{0:G}` to see the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

even so your formula is wrong, as Martin says u must replace the int.Parse with double AND

```
BMI = WeightKg / ((HeightCm/100) * (HeightCm/100));
```

use this for calculation it is HEIGHT IN METERS :)